# Papercrop not saving cropped image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I'm trying to use papercrop with paperclip to allow users to crop their photos. I have followed the documentation and referenced the test app on Github. The crop view functions fine and when I submit the form it saves the image just fine, its just that the image is the original size (not cropped).

I'm sure im missing some obvious step, so I hope that someone can point me in the right direction!!

**Model**

```
class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :photo,
                    :styles => { :medium => "300x300>", :thumb => "100x100>", :large => "800x350#" },
                    :url  => "/images//:id/:styles/:filename"
  crop_attached_file :photo
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
end
```

**Controller**

```
  def create
    @asset = Asset.new(asset_params)
    @asset.provider_id = @provider.id

    if @asset.save
      render 'crop'
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])

    if @asset.update_attributes(asset_params)
      redirect_to @provider
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end

  def crop
    @asset = Asset.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**crop.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for [@provider, @asset] do |f| %>
<%= f.cropbox :photo %>
<%= f.crop_preview :photo %>
<%= f.submit 'Save' %>
<% end %>
```

**Routes**

```
  resources :providers do
    resources :assets do
      post 'crop', :on => :member
    end
  end
```

**application.js**

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.jcrop
//= require papercrop
//= require bootstrap
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Thanks for any time spent trying to help this noob out!!

**SOLUTION**

I absentmindedly forgot to include papercrop in my strong_parameters. These were (:photo_original_w, :photo_original_h, :photo_box_w, :photo_crop_x, :photo_crop_y, :photo_crop_w, :photo_crop_h, :photo_aspect). Thank you errata!

Comment: Are you seeing anything in the logs? Also I am guessing you left out the strong_parameters code that defines asset_params. Try dumping the asset object with awesom_print or somesuch right before before saving it.

Comment: It was the strong parameters!! Will update question with info. Should I add it in an answer or would you like to write one that I can accept? Not sure what the proper ettiquette is in this case!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So it seems like you were not allowing the new attributes to be assigned using strong_parameters. Added this to make it more visible and because I'm a glutton for SO points. :-P